# how to get the value from ttk:entry

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to get the value from `ttk:entry`. I have the following code.

```
 variable DefaultRoot

 ttk::label $wi.custcfg.dlabel -text "Default Root:"
 ttk::entry $wi.custcfg.daddr -width 10 -textvariable ::DefaultRoot -validate focusout -validatecommand { puts $::DefaultRoot; return 1}

 puts $DefaultRoot
```

But I am getting error on the last puts

Comment: The variable doesn't exist until something is written into the entry. You will need to bind the output action to an event such as Return (which fires when you press and release the Return key). Like this: `bind $wi.custcfg.daddr <Return> {puts $::DefaultRoot}` (a procedure name is even better than a script here).

Comment: i tried something like this 
     `ttk::entry $wi.custcfg.daddr -width 10 -textvariable ::DefaultRoot -validate focusout -validatecommand { puts $::DefaultRoot; return 1}
    puts $DefaultRoot `
    but i still get an error on the last puts

Comment: Works fine for me. When the last puts is executed it gives an error message because the entry hasn't been used yet, but as soon as text has been entered and the entry loses focus, the puts in the validation script works fine. You can't ever expect the puts in the last line to work unless you create the variable yourself (i.e. give it a value).

Comment: Tk is event driven.  ttk::entry does not wait for entry and then continue on with the rest of the program.  Look at an example program: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html

Comment: Please include in your question the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

The variable won't exist until you set it to some value. Merely declaring it as a variable (eg: `variable DefaultRoot`) won't make it spring into existence.

With the code you posted, you're executing the last `puts` about a microsecond after creating the entry widget. The user won't have the ability to enter any text before the `puts` happens. Thus, the variable won't yet exist and the `puts` will fail.

A simple solution is to make sure to set the variable before you call `puts`, though that only means that the `puts` will print the default value.

In other words, this will print "this is the default":

```
variable DefaultRoot
set DefaultRoot "this is the default"
ttk::entry $wi.custcfg.daddr -textvariable ::DefaultRoot
puts $DefaultRoot
```

To answer your specific question, however, you can use `$::DefaultRoot` anywhere you want *after the variable has been created*.

For example, you could create a button that prints the value like this:

```
proc print_variable {} {
    puts "DefaultRoot=$::DefaultRoot"
}
ttk::button $wi.custcfg.button -text foo -command print_variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the variable anywhere via

```
global DefaultRoot
puts $DefaultRoot
```

or

```
puts $::DefaultRoot
```